# how can i make a calender on the web form using jquery

Tags: jquery, webforms

I have been given an assignment to make an event based calender on the web form. it says that the interface will comprise of Web form, CSS and Jquery. I am not sure what does it mean. should i use the calender control or make the calender on table rows and columns.

Answer (score 0):

I am looking for answers in a similar topic. i choose my calendar, which is basically what you are looking for. Check it here >> [Datepicker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/)

I am struggeling to implement it (actually i have managed that) and hadle data from it in the form itself (the email it sends after clicking submit)